# Midnight Commander Chmod command

Tags: chmod, mc

I dont know, how working difference between *Set all, Set marked and Marked all*.
Because every buttons do same things.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzAR3.png)

For change in multiple files.

Thank you.

Multiple permission in files.

Comment: If you have any question about existing software, you better ask whoever maintains that software for clarification

Answer (score 0):

From `man mc`:

> …to set the attributes exactly to those specified, you can  use the [Set all] button, which will act on all the tagged files.

This command sets and clear bits to exactly this state (the state with `[x]` and `[ ]`).

> [Marked all] set only marked attributes to all selected files

This command sets and clear marked bits (marked with `*`). I.e. it sets/clears what you changed flipping the bits from `[x]` to `[ ]` or reverse.

> [Set marked] set marked bits in attributes of all selected files

This command only sets bits marked with `*`, it doesn't clear.

Comment: @pacipaci Does the explanation make sense for you?